# Duda lineas rojas con Github

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-pull

Resulta que estoy trabajando con una compañera via github ambos estamos aprendiendo recién los comandos básicos la verdad que vamos bastante bien pero a medida que se agranda el proyecto ahora nos salen mensajes como estos **¿alguien sabe que significa esas líneas rojas?**, siempre pasan al hacer un git pull de bajar los cambios de la otra persona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece como si hubiera habido un error al hacer el merge, y se han quedado las marcas con las secciones donde hubo cambios (causando un error de sintaxis en CSS.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las líneas rojas a que te refieres no son necesariamente rojas (así te las marca tu editor). En realidad son simplemente una secuencia de signos `<<<<<<`, `=====` y `>>>>>>` que git ha introducido para señalar un **conflicto** que debes resolver manualmente.

### ¿Cuándo ocurren?

Ocurren o pueden ocurrir cuando se mezclan dos ramas. Imagina por ejemplo que tienes la siguiente secuencia de commits:

```
A -- B -- C
```

Y en ese momento se bifurca la historia y tras el commit C hay dos ramas, una en la que se realizan los commits `D` y `E` y otra en la que se realiza el commit `F`:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
           \-- F
```

En cada una de esas ramas se han hecho modificaciones diferentes a los archivos. Cuando ambas ramas se intenten reunir de nuevo, en la operación llamada *merge*, los diferentes cambios de cada rama deben combinarse. Si por ejemplo los commits `D` y `E` habían modificado el fichero `uno.txt`, mientras el commit `F` había modificado el fichero `dos.txt`, la mezcla de ambas ramas recogerá ambas modificaciones. Tras la mezcla se crea un commit nuevo, llamémosle G:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- G
           \-- F -------/
```

Ahora bien ¿qué ocurre si ambas ramas se había modificado *el mismo fichero*? En este caso la mezcla puede no ser tan sencilla. Especialmente si se habían modificado *las mismas líneas* dentro de ese fichero.

Imagina que en el commit `E` se modificó un código fuente en una línea y se metió la operación `i = i+1` en la línea modificada. En cambio, en el commit `F`, en esa misma línea se metió la instrucción `i = i-1` ¿Qué debería contener la mezcla de ambos commits? No está nada claro cuál de las dos variantes es "la buena", sólo el autor puede saberlo. Y meter ambas líneas en el resultado final obviamente también estaría mal.

En estas ocasiones git renuncia a la mezcla automática y simplemente deja en ese fichero unas marcas señalando las líneas que entraron en conflicto. Además, no genera el commit final `G` hasta que el conflicto no haya sido marcado como resuelto.

### ¿Cómo se resuelve el conflicto?

La persona que haya iniciado esta mezcla debe estar atento a los mensajes de git. Se le mostrará que ha ocurrido un conflicto y el nombre del fichero. De todas formas los conflictos son fáciles de encontrar buscando las cadenas `<<<<` y `>>>>` en los ficheros.

Lo que hay que hacer es examinar esas líneas. Lo que está comprendido entre `<<<<` y `====` son los cambios introducidos en una de las ramas, mientras que lo que hay entre `====` y `>>>>>` son los cambios introducidos en la otra rama.

El programador debe decidir cuál ha de ser el aspecto final del fichero en conflicto. Puede elegir dejar lo que viene de una de las ramas y eliminar lo de la otra. O puede escribir un código completamente nuevo que no sea el de ninguna de las dos ramas. Sea cual sea su decisión, el fichero debe quedar al final tal como le gustaría que pasara al repositorio. Y lógicamente una vez lo ha dejado a su gusto debe eliminar las marcas que señalaban el conflicto.

Una vez ha dejado el fichero a su gusto, debe hacer un `git add` de ese fichero, y después un `git commit`. Esto reanudará el *merge* interrumpido. Si había más ficheros en conflicto debe hacer esto con cada uno de ellos, hasta que el *merge* por fin tenga éxito. Esto marca el conflicto como **resuelto**.

### ¿Cómo evitarlo en primer lugar?

Este tipo de cosas pasa a menudo cuando un repositorio es compartido entre varios desarrolladores. Entonces, la copia local que cada desarrollador tiene es una especie de rama, según el esquema anterior. Cada desarrollador puede hacer cambios locales en su repositorio, y de momento el resto de desarrolladores no saben nada de los cambios introducidos por los demás. Cada uno va haciendo sus commits locales, modificando cada uno su propia copia local de la rama.

Uno de esos desarrolladores hará en algún momento un PUSH de sus cambios para subirlos al remoto. Entonces la rama almacenada en el remoto compartido se actualizará e incluirá los commits realizados por ese dessarrollador.

Cuando cualquiera de los otros desarrolladores intente hacer un PUSH, el git remoto lo rechazará. Esto es así porque, si lo aceptara, se tendrían en el remoto dos ramas separadas (cada una con los cambios realizados por cada desarrollador) y sería necesario hacer un *merge* en el repositorio remoto. Esta operación quizás dé lugar a conflictos que deban ser resueltos, y el git remoto no puede hacer eso, así que rechaza el PUSH.

El desarrollador que intentó PUSH y fue rechazado, típicamente hará un PULL. Eso descargará a su ordenador los commits que el otro desarrollador había introducido, creando una rama temporal que debe mezclar con la suya propia. Estaremos entonces en la situación que se explicó al inicio. Hay dos ramas locales que van a ser mezcladas. La mezcla puede dar conflictos y el programador que hizo pull debe resolverlos para completar con éxito el merge. Una vez los haya resuelto ya podrá hacer PUSH (y entonces el otro desarrollador deberá hacer PULL a su vez para recibir los cambios introducidos por el primero, lo que incluye también el commit de merge que resuelve los conflictos).

Todo esto se evitaría si los programadores se coordinasen un poco mejor y evitasen trabajar los dos sobre un mismo archivo. *Git no puede sustituir a la comunicación entre personas.*

Comment: Muchísimas gracias bro por responder de esa manera tan clara mi duda.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ya hay respuesta aceptada, podrian considerar leer esto que estoy haciendo al respecto del tema de conflictos (en español, sin tracking, sin monetización, contenido propio): http://www.ezconflict.com/